# Printer Turns off after Performing Printing once

Tags: printing, java-me, bluetooth, lwuit, thermal-printer

I want to Print some of the Data on Printer using Bluetooth in J2ME Application. I can Print Data perfectly fine but after completing Printing functionality, Printer turns off automatically. I mean connection to device is lost and when I close the application then it turns on automatically. I dont get why connection is lost after Printing once. Please Help me if any one has any idea. Thanks.

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.mobifin;

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
import com.sun.lwuit.Command;
import com.sun.lwuit.Component;
import com.sun.lwuit.Dialog;
import com.sun.lwuit.Display;
import com.sun.lwuit.Font;
import com.sun.lwuit.Form;
import com.sun.lwuit.Label;
import com.sun.lwuit.List;
import com.sun.lwuit.TextArea;
import com.sun.lwuit.events.ActionEvent;
import com.sun.lwuit.events.ActionListener;
import com.sun.lwuit.list.ListCellRenderer;
import com.sun.lwuit.plaf.Border;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.bluetooth.BluetoothStateException;
import javax.bluetooth.DeviceClass;
import javax.bluetooth.DiscoveryAgent;
import javax.bluetooth.DiscoveryListener;
import javax.bluetooth.LocalDevice;
import javax.bluetooth.RemoteDevice;
import javax.bluetooth.ServiceRecord;
import javax.bluetooth.UUID;
import javax.microedition.io.Connector;
import javax.microedition.io.StreamConnection;

/**
 *
 * @author riddhi.barbhaya
 */
public class PrintScreen extends Form implements ActionListener, ListCellRenderer, DiscoveryListener {

    String title;
    Form form, info;
    MobifinMidlet parent;
    Command cmd_exit = new Command("Exit", 1);
    Command cmd_Print = new Command("Print", 1);
    LocalDevice bluetooth;
    String blueStr;
    List activeDevice = new List();
    List activeServices = new List();
    DiscoveryAgent disAgent;
    Vector deviceFound;
    private ServiceRecord[] servicesFound = null;
    private boolean Dflag;
    private String connectionURL;
    private boolean srviceDisFlag;
    private DataInputStream ioDataInputStream;
    StreamConnection sc;
//    private Command cmdinfo, select;
    Display display;
    Label lbl = new Label("Searching for devices...");
    Label l1;
    int device = 0;
    String msg;

    public PrintScreen(MobifinMidlet parent, String title, String message) {
        this.title = title;
        this.setTitle(title);
        this.parent = parent;
        this.msg = message;

        this.addComponent(lbl);

        activeDevice.setListCellRenderer(this);

        this.addCommandListener(this);
        this.addComponent(activeDevice);
        this.addComponent(activeServices);


        try {
            bluetooth = LocalDevice.getLocalDevice();
        } catch (BluetoothStateException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        blueStr = bluetooth.getFriendlyName();
        disAgent = bluetooth.getDiscoveryAgent();
        deviceFound = new Vector();
        try {
            disAgent.startInquiry(DiscoveryAgent.GIAC, this);
        } catch (BluetoothStateException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            showMessageDialog("Exception", "Exception in start app");
        }
        if (Dflag) {
            disAgent.cancelInquiry(this);
        }

    }

    public void dosearchServies(RemoteDevice device) {
        int[] attributes = {0x100, 0x101, 0x102};
        UUID[] uuids;
        UUID RFCOMM_UUID = new UUID(0x1101); // RFCOMM service
        uuids = new UUID[1];
        uuids[0] = RFCOMM_UUID;
        disAgent = bluetooth.getDiscoveryAgent();
        try {
            disAgent.searchServices(null, uuids, device, this);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
//            showMessageDialog("Error", "Error");
        }
    }

    public void deviceDiscovered(RemoteDevice btDevice, DeviceClass cod) {
        try {
            String deviceaddress = null;
            try {
                deviceaddress = btDevice.getBluetoothAddress();//btDevice.getFriendlyName(true);
                System.out.println("Device Address is>>" + deviceaddress);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            String str;
            str = btDevice.getFriendlyName(true);
            activeDevice.addItem(str);
            deviceFound.addElement(btDevice);
            System.out.println("----");
            //   dosearchServies(btDevice);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            showMessageDialog("Exception", "Exception in device discovered");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void showMessageDialog(String title, String message) {
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog("Alert");
        dialog.setScrollable(false);
        dialog.setIsScrollVisible(false);
        dialog.setTimeout(2000); // set timeout milliseconds
        dialog.setPreferredH(100);
        dialog.setPreferredW(100);

        TextArea textarea = new TextArea(2, 30, TextArea.UNEDITABLE) {

            public int getRows() {
                if (isGrowByContent()) {
                    return getLines();
                } else {
                    return super.getRows();
                }
            }
        };
        textarea.getStyle().setBorder(Border.createLineBorder(0));
        textarea.getStyle().setFont(Font.createSystemFont(Font.FACE_SYSTEM, Font.STYLE_PLAIN, Font.SIZE_MEDIUM));
        textarea.getStyle().setBorder(Border.createLineBorder(0));
        textarea.setGrowByContent(true);
        textarea.setFocusable(false);
        textarea.setIsScrollVisible(false);
        textarea.setText(message);

        dialog.setTitle(title);

        dialog.addComponent(textarea);
        dialog.show(0, 120, 10, 10, true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        Command c = ae.getCommand();
        String str;
        if (c.equals(cmd_exit)) {
            MainMenu mainmenu = new MainMenu("Menu", parent);
            mainmenu.show();
        }
        else if (c.equals(cmd_Print)) {
            try {
                device = activeDevice.getSelectedIndex();
                dosearchServies((RemoteDevice) deviceFound.elementAt(device));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                showMessageDialog("Exception", "Exception in command print");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }

    private synchronized int a(int p) {
        int i = p;
        notifyAll();
        return i;
    }

    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(List list, Object value, int i, boolean isSelected) {
        Label l = new Label(value.toString());
        if (isSelected == true) {
            l.setFocus(true);
            l.setGap(0);
            l.getStyle().setFont(Font.createSystemFont(Font.FACE_SYSTEM, Font.STYLE_BOLD, Font.SIZE_MEDIUM));
        } else {
            l.setFocus(false);
            l.setGap(0);
            l.getStyle().setFont(Font.createSystemFont(Font.FACE_SYSTEM, Font.STYLE_BOLD, Font.SIZE_MEDIUM));
            return l;
        }
        return l;
    }

    public Component getListFocusComponent(List list) {
        return null;
    }

    public void serviceSearchCompleted(int i, int i1) {
        switch (i) {
            case DiscoveryListener.SERVICE_SEARCH_COMPLETED:
                srviceDisFlag = true;
                break;
            case DiscoveryListener.SERVICE_SEARCH_DEVICE_NOT_REACHABLE:
                break;
            case DiscoveryListener.SERVICE_SEARCH_ERROR:
                break;
            case DiscoveryListener.SERVICE_SEARCH_NO_RECORDS:
                break;
            case DiscoveryListener.SERVICE_SEARCH_TERMINATED:
                break;
        }
        this.setTitle("Select Device For printing Selection");


        int service = activeServices.getSelectedIndex();
        connectionURL = servicesFound[service].getConnectionURL(0, false);
        printmethod(connectionURL);

    }

    public void inquiryCompleted(int discType) {
        if (discType != DiscoveryListener.INQUIRY_COMPLETED) {

        } else {
            this.removeComponent(lbl);
            this.addCommand(cmd_Print);
            this.addCommand(cmd_exit);

            revalidate();
        }
        Dflag = true;

        try {
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void printmethod(String connection_u) {
        try {
            try {
                StreamConnection connection = (StreamConnection) Connector.open(connection_u);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[100];
                InputStream is = connection.openInputStream();
                OutputStream os = connection.openOutputStream();
                OutputStreamWriter ow = new OutputStreamWriter(os, "US-ASCII");
                InputStreamReader ir = new InputStreamReader(is, "US-ASCII");
                ow.write(msg);
                ow.flush();
                ow.close();
                connection.close();
                showMessageDialog("", "Please Wait Printing is in Progress");

                MainMenu menu=new MainMenu("Menu", parent);
                menu.show();


                System.out.println("-4-");
                System.out.println("-5-");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error " + e);
                showMessageDialog("Exception", e.toString());
            }

            int i2 = 0;
            System.out.println("-0-");

    }

    public void servicesDiscovered(int i, ServiceRecord[] srs) {
        servicesFound = srs;
    }

    public void addText(String text) {
        TextArea t = new TextArea(2, 30, TextArea.UNEDITABLE) {

            public int getRows() {
                if (isGrowByContent()) {
                    return getLines();
                } else {
                    return super.getRows();
                }
            }
        };
        t.getStyle().setBorder(Border.createLineBorder(0));
        t.setGrowByContent(true);
        t.setText(text);
        this.addComponent(t);
    }
}
```

Comment: every time when you make connection with you device after transferring of data sockets closed. so you need to start whole process from beginning. its just an idea.

Comment: @DeepSan.. Thanks for your reply. You are absolutely correct. For other Platforms like Android, we need to close data socket connection. but for J2ME, no idea. because I checked after closing all connections. If any idea, then please reply me.

Comment: as per my little knowledge,the behavior of the sockets same in both platform. It is generic behavior we always use open and close methods to control. Now what is the problem you are facing.